# converting a nested field to a list json in logstash

Tags: logstash

I want to convert a field to a json list, sg like this:
"person": {
"name":"XX",
"adress":"124"
}

to

"person": [{"name":"XX",
"adress":"124"}]

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: Are the name fields hardcoded (always name + address) ? Also out of curiosity, what is the point of this? How is a list with random key-value pairs going to be used? This will most likely have to be the ruby filter as this will involve some custom logic

Comment: name and  address are extracted from xml file into fields. I want to create a new field that is a list of name and adress fields. The reason is that I have a module wich is waiting for a list json to parse it and extract data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of ruby magic will do here:

```
input {  
    stdin{}
}

filter {

    ruby {
        code => "
            require 'json'
            event['res'] = [JSON.parse(event['message'])['person']]
        "
    }

}


output {
     stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

This will simply parse your `message` field containing your Json document, then extract the `person` object and add it to a field.

The test looks as such:

```
    artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf_json_list/ 
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
{ "person": { "name":"XX", "adress":"124" }}
{
       "message" => "{ \"person\": { \"name\":\"XX\", \"adress\":\"124\" }}",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2017-03-15T11:34:37.424Z",
          "host" => "pandaadb",
           "res" => [
        [0] {
              "name" => "XX",
            "adress" => "124"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, your hash now lives in a list on index 0.

Hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: it works thank you very much.. another suggestion is :   

ruby {
        code => "
            event['aa'] = [event['aa']]
        "
    }